# How to Open Google App Permissions on Button Click?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have implemented a Button Onclick Listener function, Now I need to Open Google App Permission inside setting on Button Click.

```
Button buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXName);
// Register the onClick listener with the implementation above
buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        **How to Open Below Permission (Check Image Below)**
    } 
});
```

[How to Open Google App Permission(Left side in Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj7JQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done directly. You can open the Settings page via intent and then you can move to app permission page by using manual clicks. In order to open Setting page pass the Intent as:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Did it helped you @Naveen ??